# How to make a password authentication with QR for a django html form

Tags: html, django, wagtail

I have made a password protected page with django and cms wagtail, i need the following cases to happen:

If user enters the url normally: page requires him a password through an HTML form, and don't get him access to it until it gives the correct password (Done).

If user enters with a QR code: page doesn't require him the password, and get him immediate access to the content page.

Models.py:

```
from wagtail.core.models import Page, PageViewRestriction
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class ProfilePage(Page):
    template = 'profile/profile_page.html'

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        
        return context

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        your_page = ProfilePage.objects.all().first()
        PageViewRestriction.objects.create(page=your_page, restriction_type='password')

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

password template (wagtail's default one):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Password required</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Password required</h1>
        <p>You need a password to access this page.</p>
        <form action="{{ action_url }}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {{ form.non_field_errors }}

            <div>
                {{ form.password.errors }}
                {{ form.password.label_tag }}
                {{ form.password }}
            </div>

            {% for field in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need your QR code url to go to a view that automatically logs the person into the public side of your site and then redirects to the restricted page. This implies that either you have a shared account for viewing the restricted content (aka a guess account) OR that you will be creating separate QR codes for each user/url combination.

Comment: Yes, my need is to restrict the view of the pages, and then make that the users either through password or login can access, but it needs to be a QR that makes this, the problem is i have no idea how to start this, because on this case, it would mean i need to do something similar of the second choice you said, because the guest user would always be the same but the link needs to redirect to a specific page, not a list of pages.

My problem in that case, is: How can i put the login of the user AND redirect it to the specific page in question on the same QR?

Comment: So i ended up making a page with an auto-log of a guest user, give the QR code a link with a param (/somethings?=X for example), and then the page substracts that param and send the user to the corresponding page through the slugs in the wagtail pages, after that el user is automatically loged-out so it can't go to another pages, not my prefered method but it's what i did with what i knew, i still wish to know if it's a concrete answer to the question or a better method.